# Directional Derivatives without a given function

Tags: calculus

In the question I am attempting, I must find partial derivatives of f(x,y) at co-ordinates (a,b)

I am given that the directional derivative in the direction of the vector (1,2) is 2, and in direction of the vector (-1,1) is 3.

Can anyone give me a hint of how to tackle this?

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Can you write down "the directional derivative in the direction of the vector $\langle 1,2\rangle$" in terms of $f_x$ and $f_y$?